# Is there a Python function to get 20 decimal digits of the float variables

Tags: python, floating-point, double, precision

My computation is not giving expected results so I am trying to have equal number of digits (say 20) after decimal point in all my variables (int, float). The variables contains real and complex numbers. Some of my variables are:

a11 = -8.37

a22 = 8.305E-5

a33 = 0

a44 = 2.6645352591003757e-15+1.7763568394002505e-15j

I want the variables to have numeric values like

a11 = -8.36999999999999999999

a22 = 0.00830500000000000000

a33 = 0.00000000000000000000

a44 = 0.00000000000000266454+0.00000000000000177636j

I tried using *"{:.20f}".format(x)* command but the output variable is a string, so I could not perform mathematical operations with the variables

ex: a44 = "{:.20f}".format(a44)

```
a44 + a44
```

output:

0.00000000000000266454+0.00000000000000177636j0.00000000000000266454+0.00000000000000177636j

which is just concatenation of strings. Whereas the outcome must be

0.00000000000000532907+0.00000000000000355271j

I know this might not be the solution to my problem in my computation but I am suspecting that the results might be deviated due to unequal number of decimal digits in variables and the errors are accumulated due to iterations in my program.

Is there any way I can achieve this in python?
Thanks.

Comment: float doesn't have that much precision. You can print more digits but those aren't quite meaningful

Comment: Also, leaving aside the problem of the precision, why would you want to have the representation of the float have trailing zeros for mathematical operations? Either you care about the math and you should just let python handle the objects without worrying about the internal representation, or you care about representation sand you should use strings.

Comment: Note: -8.37 not exactly representable as `float`.  Closest exact value is `-8.3699999999999992184029906638897955417633056640625`.  `a11 =` `-8.36999999999999921840` is a better _like_ goal.

Comment: @phuclv seeing number such as 2.664E-15 you may think decimal digits aren't important but when you are doing atomic scale calculations and have to use standard units of measurements like meter, every digits upto 15th decimal place is important

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yeah I need the closest exact value like the one you showed.

Comment: @RohinKc the problem is you are dealing with fixed-precision, binary floating point numbers. You could try to use `decimal.Decimal` objects, which will behave more like you expect, but it will slow things down. Just remember, initialize with `str` and `int` only, not `float`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#quick-start-tutorial Probably want to use `getcontext().traps[FloatOperation] = True`

Comment: RohinKc, [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485) is how I get the exact value as decimal text in C.

Comment: @RohinKc: `float` precision is not measured as digits after the fixed decimal point. It is **floating** point arithmetic. The scale **floats** with an exponent. Precision is relative to the exponent (and, in binary formats, is measured in bits, not decimal digits). The `float` format that most Python implementations use is perfectly capable of representing `2.664E-15` very accurately. But they cannot represent `1 + 2.664E-15` accurately.

Comment: That said, it is not clear what your actual problem is. The question states the output is “0.00000000000000266454+0.00000000000000177636j0.00000000000000266454+0.00000000000000177636j” but you want “0.00000000000000532907+0.00000000000000355271j”. So it appears you want to add two complex numbers before formatting them as numerals. So why don’t you? Presumably there are some variables in your code, and you could add them before formatting. But you have not shown us the code. Since we cannot see the code, we cannot diagnose what is wrong with it. You need to clarify the question.